# In field matching records retrieve using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table `Chapters` which contains three columns

```
id, QuestionId, QuestionText
```

Sample data:

```
Id    QuestionId    QuestionText
---------------------------------------------------
 1       12         Biology Nuclear Lining
 2       13         Chemistry Molecules
 3       14         Molecular dividing
 4       15         Biology Planting
 4       15         Physics Elevator
```

Now I need to retrieve the data based on the `QuestionText` column which contains text matching with same field not fully matching.

My output needs to be like this:

```
Id    QuestionId    QuestionText
---------------------------------------------------
 1       12         Biology Nuclear Lining
 4       15         Biology Planting
 2       13         Chemistry Molecules
 3       14         Molecular dividing
```

Similar words are in each data. At least 40% words are same then I need to retrieve it. I am using SQL Server, can anyone help me please how to write the query, what method I need to use?

Comment: you can use order by question id

Comment: i need to do this using pattern matching mechanism, if words are same in question text then only the matching record will come other records will not retrieve.

Comment: @Ravu You need to that kind of information in your question, people in here are not psychics

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius sorry i can't understand what you are expecting.only three fields in it .only one table no other tables.i need to retrieve matching records  based on questionText field(its fully matching or partially matching or words matching).

Comment: Please post the sql you have tried so far. It may help us understand what you are looking for